# Escaping sed strings correctly

Tags: bash, sed, escaping

I have a regex and replacement pattern that have both been tested in Notepad++ on my input data and work correctly.  When I put them into a sed expression, however, nothing gets matched.

Here is the sed command:

```
 # SEARCH = ([a-zA-Z0-9.]+) [0-9] (.*)
 # REPLACE = \2 (\1)

 sed -e 's/\([a-zA-Z0-9.]+\) [0-9] \(.*\)/\2 \(\1\)/g'
```

Here is a sampling of the data:

```
jdoe 1 Doe, John
jad 1 Doe, Jane
smith 2 Smith, Jon
```

and the desired output:

```
Doe, John  (jdoe)
Doe, Jane  (jad)
Smith, Jon (smith)
```

I have tried removing and adding escapes to different characters in the sed expression, but either get nothing matched or something along the lines of:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 42: invalid reference \2 on `s' command's RHS
```

How can I get this escaped correctly?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I usually find it easier to use the -r switch as this means that escaping is similar to that of most other languages:

```
sed -r 's/([a-zA-Z0-9.]+) [0-9] (.*)/\2 (\1)/g' file1.txt
```

Answer (score 9):

A few warnings and additions to what everyone else has already said:

1. The `-r` option is a GNU extension to enable extended regular expressions. BSD derived sed's use `-E` instead.
2. [Sed](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/utilities/sed.html#tag_04_126_13_02) and [Grep](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/utilities/grep.html) use [Basic Regular Expressions](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/basedefs/xbd_chap09.html#tag_09_03)
3. [Awk](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/utilities/awk.html#tag_04_06_13_04) uses [Extended Regular Expressions](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/basedefs/xbd_chap09.html#tag_09_04)
4. You should become comfortable with the [POSIX specifications](http://www.opengroup.org/pubs/catalog/un.htm) such as [IEEE Std 1003.1](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/toc.htm) if you want to write portable scripts, makefiles, etc.

I would recommend rewriting the expression as

```
's/\([a-zA-Z0-9.]\{1,\}\) [0-9] \(.*\)/\2 (\1)/g'
```

which should do exactly what you want in any POSIX compliant `sed`.  If you do indeed care about such things, consider defining the [`POSIXLY_CORRECT`](http://www.wlug.org.nz/POSIXLY_CORRECT) environment variable.

Answer (score 4):

The plus sign needs to be escaped when not using the `-r` switch.

Answer (score 2):

Using awk is much simpler...:

```
cat test.txt | awk '{ print $3 " " $4 " " "("$1")" }'
```

Output:

```
Doe, John (jdoe)
Doe, Jane (jad)
Smith, Jon (smith)
```

See man awk [1](http://bash.vc/cgi-bin/man/man2html?query=awk)

Answer (score 1):

```
$ sed -e 's/\([a-zA-Z0-9.].*\) [0-9] \(.*\)/\2 \(\1\)/g' file
Doe, John (jdoe)
Doe, Jane (jad)
Smith, Jon (smith)
```